# MeshDataTool corrupting normals. What could be wrong?

Tags: godot

When opening a mesh with MeshDataTool, even if I don't do any changes, committing the mesh turns it darker.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that the obj file was indexed

Comment: Consider marking this answer as Accepted if it solved your problem.